# Passing a function to another function via "pass by value"

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

Code

```
void printA()
{
   cout << "A\n";
}

void print1( void (*func_ptr)(void) )
{
   func_ptr();
}

void print2( void func(void))
{
   func();
}

int main()
{
  //Method 1a (passing function pointer)
  print1(&printA);
  //Method 1b (why does it work even though I didn't pass a reference or a pointer?)
  print1(printA);

  //Method 2 (passing the whole function ?)
  print2(printA);

  return 0;
}
```

Method 1a makes sense: print1 was expecting a reference or pointer. 
Question 1: 
Method 1b does not make sense: Why doesn't the compiler throw an error. Why does it work, even though I didn't pass the reference or the pointer of printA() to print1()? 
Question 2: 
Method 2a implies a new copy of the function printA() is made and passed to function print2().
In other words, is the function printA() is passed to function print2() by value? 
Question 3: 
Are identifiers of functions references? (this might help) 
Much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter of this function declaration

```
void print2( void func(void));
```

is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the function type that is to

```
void print2( void ( *func )(void));
```

The both above declarations declare the same one function and may be both present in the same compilation unit though the compiler can issue a message that there are redundant function declarations.

On the other hand, a function designator used as an argument for such a function shown above is implicitly converted to a pointer to the function.

You may even write for example

```
print2(**********printA);
```

Thus as for this your question

> Method 2a implies a new copy of the function printA() is made and
> passed to function print2(). In other words, is the function printA()
> is passed to function print2() by value?

then neither copy of the function is passed. It is a pointer to the function that is passed.